# Drupal + Webmaster Tools: "This url is not allowed for a Sitemap at this location."

Tags: drupal, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I'm using the XMLSitemap module on a new Drupal 7 site. The sitemap is generated fine, but Google Webmaster Tools doesn't like it. The file has 61 entries, and I get 61 identical errors: "This url is not allowed for a Sitemap at this location." So it won't process the file.

My Webmaster Tools account displays `http://example.com` as the base URL. My sitemap specifies the same — `http://example.com` — for all links. On the site, I do have an .htaccess rule that redirects all requests to `https://example.com`. However, if I change the base URL setting in the sitemap to https, I still get the same error messages.

I should add that I have the XMLSitemap module set up to automatically submit my sitemap to Google, but I did not see that reflected anywhere in Webmaster Tools. To make sure it was submitted, I manually input the sitemap URL (`http://example.com/sitemap.xml`) into Webmaster Tools. That is how I'm able to see any output at all.

How can I get Google to like this file?

Comment: Please provide a link to you sitemap.xml

Comment: https://northerncoloradocu.org/sitemap.xml

Comment: added answer, domain spelt wrong in sitemap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain is spelt wrong in your sitemap.
"http://northerncoloradcu.org" - missing "o".
I am not sure how this would have happened, but you can regenerate the sitemap at the path: "admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/rebuild".

Comment: Wow. Don't know how this happened, or how I missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of the domain name is different in sitemap links and google webmaster tools. (maybe you need to check for case sensitivity, or www with/without).